# How to tell distcp to ignore "file not found ..." and fall through to the next files?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

We have a full HDFS backup using `distcp` that takes a long time to run, some of the data on HDFS is "moving", that is it is created and deleted.  This results in mappers failing with `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory`.  Such files are unimportant, we just want the backup to do the best it can.

Now it seems that `-i` "ignore failures" is not quite what we want because it will ignore at the *map level* rather than the file level, that is if a map task fails all files associated to that map task will be ignored.  What we want is just that file to be ignored.

Comment: That's not right.  "-i" ignores at the file/directory level instead of the mapper level.